# How do you keep a program running after Standby?

Tags: .net, windows-xp

I wrote a very simple .Net windows application that sits in the system tray and queries a db every 15 minutes.  It works great without any issues, except when the computer goes into standby mode.  After the user wakes the computer back up, the icon in the system tray is gone, and the program is no longer running.

How can I make it so that the program continues running after a standby or hibernate?  I have very little control over the box settings since this is a corporate environment, but I could make changes to the program itself if there is a way to do this through code.

The OS is XP - some will be upgraded to Windows 7 soon.
Im using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: How, on earth, can you run a program on a computer that is *turned off* (hibernate)???

Comment: @Will Did you read the question?  He's asking for the program to still be there *after* resuming from standby / hibernate.

Comment: @Will he means that after it resumes the program stops working I think

Comment: Process resume where they left off after standby/hibernate - your app obviously crashed or decided to shutdown. Add some logging to work out which it is.

Comment: @Sam right.  It runs in the background while a user is doing their normal work.  Then the user goes home at night and the computer goes into standby.  When they come back in the next morning and wake the computer up, the app isnt working anymore.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps it is some issue like the db connection that is causing it crash, but I thought putting the computer on standby would essentially disable network connections, etc. and then reenable them after waking up.  Im more internet developer than windows.  I like the idea of adding some logging.  Will logging work if it crashes on standby?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, I did read it.  **"How can I make it so that the program continues running after a standby or hibernate?"**  Language is a hell of a barrier.

Comment: @rahkim: also, you probably aren't handling shutdown well and the app is crashing/being forcibly shut down during standby/hibernation.  Check the event logs to see if there are any errors regarding this.

Comment: I tried logging to the event log, but it appears our policy settings prohibit that.  I put in a hack and just put a try-catch block around the database calls.  That seems to work...but its awefully hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already runs after a system suspension, if it was running during the suspend! Probably, you application exits after having started the wake up or just before the suspension.

It could be a crash, but this would show an informative error message.

You need to track the application execution (i.e. A log system), then find the problem and fix it. Maybe the network connnection could be the point of failure, but not sure: the DB connection is still valid after a standby?

Comment: Im not sure what causes the crash but when I ignore any errors, the program is still running when the computer is back up after standby mode.  I think the error relates to either the timer control or the db call since that is essentially all the app does.  My guess is that the db call bugs out.